# Close Dart Stream that doesn't use StreamSubscription?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple function that returns a Stream. Works great:

```
Stream<List<User>> streamPeopleToFollow({@required User startAfterUser}) {
  Query query = _usersRef.orderBy('dateTime', descending: false).limit(20);

 if (startAfterUser != null) 
   query = query.startAfter([startAfterUser.dateTime.toIso8601String()]);

 return query.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
   return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
     return User.fromJson(doc.data());
   }).toList();
 });
}
```

I give to a StreamBuilder:

```
     :
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: streamPeopleToFollow(startAfterUser),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
     :
```

When "startAfterUser" changes, the widget with the StreamBuilder rebuilds and I get my updated list, so the old stream is abondoned. This all is working fine. My question is about the disposed Stream--I don't see any "close" or "cancel" functions in the Stream class. Does it close when its disposed? I obviously want to avoid dangling streams.

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L156

Comment: Ah. So the StreamBuilder manages the subscription and unsubscribes on dispose. Perfect!